# Wordpress Blocks, setAttributes not saving

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, metabox, block-editor

My block seems to work correctly, unfortunately none of my metadata gets saved after saving the article.

You can find source code for my block [**in this repository**](https://github.com/creativiii/ironeko-featured-content/blob/master/src/index.js). It simply adds a toggle to set a meta value to false or true.

While the value to my attribute seems to change after calling:

```
setAttributes( { featured: value } );
```

If I save my post and check the rest api, the value actually won’t have changed.

I have absolutely no clue why this isn’t working. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer, what exactly do you mean by "the value actually won’t have changed"? It's not displaying?

Comment: The meta attribute wasn't changing. It displayed in the Rest API as false and despite calling setAttributes it refused to change to true. I have solved it and it wasn't a problem with my JS code. I'll write an answer later today.